# ASP.NET 5 (MVC 6) - Resources Localization

Tags: asp.net-core

I have spent about one week trying to understand how Localization is going to work in ASP.NET Core 1.0. I have tested a lot of options, but I can't make it working.

I have read about the bug in [Visual Studio](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/153), I have read all articles about how it's working right now ([Article1](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/how-aspnet5-determines-culture-info-for-localization), [Article2](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/setting-thread-culture-aspnet5), [Article3](http://damienbod.com/2015/10/21/asp-net-5-mvc-6-localization/)) and I have check and tested all about the [example](https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/tree/dev/samples/LocalizationSample) in the Official GitHub Repository.

**My Goal:**

I just want to make it works like I did in ASP.NET MVC 5.

I have configured my Startup.cs like this:

*Configure Section:*

```
var requestLocalizationOptions = new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                // Set options here to change middleware behavior
                SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                    new CultureInfo("es-ES")
                },
                SupportedUICultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                {
                    new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                   new CultureInfo("es-ES")

                }
            };

            app.UseRequestLocalization(requestLocalizationOptions, defaultRequestCulture: new RequestCulture("en-US"));
```

*Configure Services Section:*

```
// Add MVC services to the services container.
            services
                .AddMvc()
                .AddViewLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources")
                .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();
```

In my folder Resources, I have my .resx files. I have copied it from the official example, but no way... No errors, just not working.

If I test the Localization example of the official Repo, it works. But I can't modified to adapt to MVC 6.

I have created a repository on GitHub for my code and test it. (https://github.com/chemitaxis/Localization.StackOverflow)

Can someone please help me? I think a lot of people is having these problems.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I solved it... I will update my example on GitHub tomorrow.

I have created a **_ViewImports**, and add it:

```
@addTagHelper "*, Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers"
@using System.Threading.Tasks
@using AspNet5Localization
@using AspNet5Localization.Resources
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Localization
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
@inject IStringLocalizer<AmazingResource> SR
```

After, I have created a **HomeController** and **Views/Home/Index.cshtml** file.

Like I have injected in my *Views* in **_ViewImports** the **IStringLocalizer SR** I can use it in my Razor Views using just:

```
@SR["Name"]
```

I don't know if it the best way to do that, but it works. If someone can explain the best way to do that, please answer this question.

Complete solution working: https://github.com/chemitaxis/Localization.StackOverflow

Thanks.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. I tried to run the example for RC2 https://github.com/damienbod/AspNet5Localization/tree/rc2 where however I couldn't manage. I had issues related to the rc2 version of dnx. Have you managed to run this version?

Comment: Not yet... I will do later. I will upgrade in new branch

Comment: Can you add example localization with data annotations. I tried `[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Name_is_required", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(PersonalInfo))]
        [MaxLength(Constants.MaxNameLength)]
        public string Name { get; set; }` but it does not work.

Comment: It's sad to see that, after so many years and a big CORE rebranding, we're still stuck with this ugly solution for localization, involving .resx files, but now with one more level of indirection involving interfaces and dependency injection. Sad, very sad. I supose that Microsoft has left this for the open source community to get on, and there's nobody working paid for this, because if there is, they aren't deserving their salaries...

Comment: I agree with @Vi100, localization still is very ugly... I will wait for https://github.com/turquoiseowl/i18n/issues/293

Comment: Our team have back to 4.5, and we are migrating now to Node.js with Express... We are a Startup with more than 200 K users and growing 1.5 K users per day... Microsoft is not ready today for this kind of project... I thought that Core will be the solution, but maybe in some years... my worst decision was choose Core RC1...